# How to configure Freeradius to use PEAP as an outer method and EAP-TLS as the inner Method?

Tags: radius, freeradius

I am currently using Freeradius 3.0 to setup remote authentication server for wireless testing.  So far I have gotten every configuration working except the following:

PEAP / EAP-TLS

I found an article that is about 4.5 years old here: http://notes.asd.me.uk/2012/01/20/freeradius-with-peap-eap-tls-for-microsoft-soh/

However after following the above article and changing it to work with the Freeradius 3.0 by modifying the following files:

1. /raddb/mods-available/eap
2. /raddb/mods-available/inner-eap and creating a symbolic link from this file to /raddb/mods-enabled.
3. /raddb/sites-available/inner-tunnel

After making the changes, PEAP (no inner method) no longer seems to be working.  Though removing references to inner-eap in the mods-available folder seems to get it working again.

Any thoughts on how to setup the configurations to allow for PEAP / EAP-TLS?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Solution found!

Problem is RTFM.  In the inner-tunnel configuration file I had both eap and inner-eap listed as Auth-Types.  I commented out the eap sections and everything works beautifully!

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I cannot brain, I has the dumb.  I was a moron and had both eap and inner-eap defined as Auth-Types in /raddb/mods-available/inner-tunnel.

Just commented out the eap method references in the authorization and authentication sections and everything works fine.